# posicionamiento absoluto CSS

Tags: css, css3, scss

Hola comunidad actualmente estoy teniendo un problema con un valor de posicionamiento absoluto. Resulta que he puesto la regla pero luego no puedo resetear el valor.

Esto es el valor normal seria para una imagen en SVG

```css
 .kit {
               
                img {
                    width:60%;
                    bottom: 40px;
                    right: 40px;
                    position:absolute;
                    vertical-align: top;  
                }
            }
```

Lo que intento es hacer que el valor absoluto vuelva a seguir el orden de la maqueta HTML. Ya he intentado con varias cosas y sin ningún resultado:

> position:relative !important; //sin resultado
>   position:static !important; //sin resultado

¿Que podrá ser?

Comment: Según entiendo, el valor absoluto de 'img' resulta absoluto respecto al posicionamiento de 'kit'. que no aparece en tu código y de ese modo es heredado. Quizás, los elementos superiores estén determinando la posición y por eso no se comporte como esperas.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta, quiza lo puedas resolver con `display:inline` o `display:inline-block`pero sin mas información ni estoy seguro.

Comment: `position: static` deferia funcionar ya que es el posicionamiento por defecto de los elementos y no le afectan la propiedades `top`, `bottom`, `left` y `right`. Otra opción sería usar los valores `initial` o `unset` que devuelven el valor original a la propiedad en la que se usa. De todas formas estaría bien si puedes creas un [mcve] donde se reproduzca el problema para ver que está pasando

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Bueno luego de batallar me fuí a la documentación de CSS me dí cuenta de que el valor abosluto cuando se desmaqueta para volverlo a maquetar colocandolo dentro de un position:relative; con un tamaño en ese caso añadir fue un height: 500px; de esa forma me permitio ajustar sus tamaños y listo santo remedio. Saludos!